# ambient occlusion bug?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

In the latest blender versions the ambient occlusion is strange. If i activate ambient occlusion, the shadows disapears if i set ambient occlusion on low forexample 0,50, the shadows disapears, and if i taking ot on 1.0, the shadows are weak. Before, ambient occlusion was like when i set it on low, the shadows were more visible and hard, and if i took it on high, it was more unclear shadows. Is it going to be a fix for ambient occlusion like it was before, soon?

Im using a matchmove-camera imported from syntheyes.

---

is there something i must change in the camera object?

[image: high value ambient occlusion]

[image: low value ambient occlusion]

it happens in any camera render, it has nothing to do with syntheyes matchmoved scene, i found out right now.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the situation? Maybe two, one with the issue and one as example of what would have been "Before". Which versions of Blender are you referring to?

Comment: im using the last version of blender. it seems to be only when i using a solved matchmoving scene from syntheyes. is there something i must change in the camera?

Comment: i found out it has nothing to do with matchmove scene from syntheyes. it happends with any camera.

Comment: ok. now i found out i had to change from shadows and shading in shadow only to shadow only in the drop down menu. now it works.

Comment: Good! If you have exactly found our what the problem was, consider to write down and accept you own answer, so who'll fall into the same issue can easily find a solution.